# Android Room Test Delete Not Working (Java)

Tags: java, android, testing, android-room, dao

I'm trying to unit-test my DAO using android-room. I have written an insert test that works properly. Unfortunately, the delete method doesn't seem to be working.

I've tried a few different setups for the test. None have worked.

Here is the DAO:

```java
@Dao
public interface MonthlyDao {

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    void saveAll(List<Monthly> goals);

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    void save(Monthly goal);

    @Update
    void update(Monthly goal);

    @Delete
    void delete(Monthly goal);

    @Query("SELECT * FROM Monthly")
    LiveData<List<Monthly>> findAll();

    @Query("SELECT * FROM monthly")
    List<Monthly> findAllList();
}
```

Here is the Monthly entity:

```java
@Entity
public class Monthly {
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    private int monthlyId;

    @TypeConverters(CalendarTypeConverter.class)
    @ColumnInfo(name = "date")
    private Calendar date = Calendar.getInstance();

    @ColumnInfo(name = "title")
    private String title;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "description")
    private String description;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "completed")
    private boolean completed;
...
    public int getMonthlyId() {
        return monthlyId;
    }

    public void setMonthlyId(int monthlyId) {
        this.monthlyId = monthlyId;
    }
```

And here is the test I am running:

```java
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
public class MonthlyTest {
    private MonthlyDao monthlyDao;
    private MonthlyGoalsDatabase db;

    @Before
    public void createDb() {
        Context context = ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext();
        db = Room.inMemoryDatabaseBuilder(context, MonthlyGoalsDatabase.class).build();
        monthlyDao = db.getMonthlyDao();
    }

    @After
    public void closeDb() throws IOException {
        db.close();
    }

    @Test
    public void deleteGoal() throws Exception {
        String title = "test delete title";
        Calendar date = Calendar.getInstance();
        date.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
        String desc = "test delete desc";
        Monthly goal = new Monthly(title, date, desc);
        monthlyDao.save(goal);
        List<Monthly> goals = monthlyDao.findAllList();
        Assert.assertThat(goals.get(0).getTitle(), equalTo(goal.getTitle()));
        monthlyDao.delete(goal);
        List<Monthly> updatedGoals = monthlyDao.findAllList();
        Assert.assertTrue(updatedGoals.isEmpty());
    }
```

I except the updatedGoals list to be empty, but it isn't. There is still the goal that I inserted during the test.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The method annotated with `@Delete` uses the primary key on the entity to know which row to delete from the database (because there could be multiple rows with the same data but different keys).

However, you're using the initial `goal` object that you created, which *has no primary key*, and thus cannot be used to indicate which row to remove.

Try doing this:

```
monthlyDao.save(goal);
List<Monthly> goals = monthlyDao.findAllList();
Assert.assertThat(goals.get(0).getTitle(), equalTo(goal.getTitle()));
monthlyDao.delete(goals.get(0)); // <-- Delete the goal returned from the find, which will have an ID
List<Monthly> updatedGoals = monthlyDao.findAllList();
Assert.assertTrue(updatedGoals.isEmpty());
```

That could easily be cleaned up a bit, but the above example only changes one line, to make it clear where the issue is.

See [here](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/accessing-data) for the relevant documentation.

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thanks for the answer and link to more info.